# Conditional formatting issue while converting .XLS to .XLSM using Spire.XLS

Tags: excel, spire.xls

I am using Spire.XLS to convert **XLS** files to **.XLSM** files.

```
Spire.Xls.Workbook lobjDSTemplateWorkbook = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
lobjDSTemplateWorkbook.DisableMacrosStart = false;
lobjDSTemplateWorkbook.LoadFromFile(pstrIPDTemplatePath);
lobjDSTemplateWorkbook.SaveToFile(lstrOpenXMLXLSMIPDTemplatePath, Spire.Xls.ExcelVersion.Version2013);
```

Doing so, It is asking for repair when trying to open converted .XLSM file and giving following error, after repair.

> Removed Feature: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml
>   part

This is due to 'Conditional Formatting' existed in second sheet. How to fix this?

Does Spire.XLS (v 8.3.0.61040 free version) doesn't support conversion of file if it contains conditional formatting?

If I am able to consider only first sheet for conversion to .xlsm file, that also ok. Can we select 'Sheets' like that for conversion.